# Docker does not have default machine in Windows 10

Tags: docker

I installed Docker in Windows 10 64bit. The built is also correct and it is a pro version so it shouldn't be a problem.

Docker activated Hyper-V and created the docker machine, which I can access to load page in localhost. The syncing is also working so my Docker container is working overall (I used Laradock).

My problem is when I try to connect to the MySQL from my host machine, I can't connect through localhost or 127.0.0.1. Ports are correct too I have checked.

> Amendment: If I leave the host box blank, PhpMyAdmin works. But I
>   still can't connet through SQLYog or other clients.

I tried doing `docker-machine ip` and I get this:

`Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exists.`

Here's my `docker ps` output:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
85cce33afbe2        laradock_nginx        "nginx"                  12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   laradock_nginx_1
f2ce18b4591c        laradock_php-fpm      "php-fpm"                12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       9000/tcp                                   laradock_php-fpm_1
23bf95305334        laradock_workspace    "/sbin/my_init"          12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       0.0.0.0:2222->22/tcp                       laradock_workspace_1
f7b87216173b        laradock_phpmyadmin   "/run.sh phpmyadmin"     12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                       laradock_phpmyadmin_1
4a87449e2bb6        laradock_mysql        "docker-entrypoint.sh"   12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3306->1234/tcp           laradock_mysql_1
```

**After the fix:**

> I am still not getting the 'default' machine and can't do
>   `docker-machine ip` but by changing the port mapping from 1234 to 3306
>   I got SQLYog to work too. It'll do for me for now.
>
> So I mapped opposite. I have to map to 3306 from 1234 which means I have to do "1234:3306" in my docker-compose.yml file. That worked too. :D

**The discussion below, fixed my problem but I can still use some solution to why 'default' machine is not working and I can't do `docker-machine ip`.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> VirtualBox VMs created with docker-machine (including the default one typically created during Toolbox install) will no longer start. These VMs cannot be used side-by-side with Docker for Windows.

[Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/)

You don't use `docker-machine`. You list the containers with `docker ps`. If you cannot access the MySQL container, then you might have forgotten to expose the port.

> My problem is when I try to connect to the MySQL from my host machine, I can't connect through localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Sounds like you're connecting wrong. It is definitely running.

```
4a87449e2bb6        laradock_mysql        "docker-entrypoint.sh"   12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3306->1234/tcp
```

Though, unclear why you mapped to port 1234

Comment: I use Docker for Windows. Docker Toolbox just didn't work for me os I uninstalled it.

Comment: I am using Laradoc (https://github.com/laradock/laradock). And port is exposed at "3306:1234".

Comment: I don't know what to tell you - haven't used Laradoc. I'm just answering your Docker question. (The compose file is set as `- "3306:3306"`, though

Comment: I tried to be smart and tried to expose and map 1234 to 3306. At least that's what I thought it did. When I put it back to "3306:3306" it worked.

Comment: lol! So I mapped opposite. I have to map to 3306 from 1234 which means I have to do "1234:3306". That worked too. :D

Comment: Yes, the order is `hostPort:containerPort`. MySQL's container port would be 3306